# TaskTimer not working in a game loop

Tags: java, swing, timer, runnable, event-dispatch-thread

I want to make a simple pause function that is within a game loop that uses TaskTimer, but it's not functioning. Is there something wrong with the task timer? Should I be using another util? I've been stuck on this for a while now.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class test extends JFrame implements KeyListener, Runnable {
    public boolean pause = false;

    public test() {
        new JFrame();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    while (true) {
        if (pause) {
            System.out.println("Paused");
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Some Pause Related Task");
                    pause = false;
                }
            }, (long) 3000);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    char c = e.getKeyChar();
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        System.out.println("typed space");
        pause = true;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new test();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) isn't `focusable JComponent`s, won't react to `KeyEvent`, then (never) [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) doesn't works, is required to use `focusable JComponent` (put there `JPanel` and to with `setFocusable(`)), but not proper of possible ways
2. `Swing JComponents` are designated to use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of lowlevel [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) (with another side effect in compare with `KeyBindings`)
3. use [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) only in the case that there are three or more `Keys pressed` e.i.
4. use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of `util.Timer`, output from [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) notified [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), otherwise you have to calculating with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a swing timer instead of a utility timer. It is tailored for swing apps that need a periodic callback. The callbacks go to an `ActionListener` and occur in the EDT. I am also puzzled by the line `new JFrame()` in your constructor. It, quite frankly, is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You never call `run()` to start the timer. I also recommend following tbodt's advice to use swing [Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of the general purpose timers in swing programs.

```
public void main() {
    // Swing components should be modified only in the event dispatch thread.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            test t = new test(); // test class should really be renamed to Test to follow java naming conventions
            t.run();
        }
    });
}
```

Furthermore, remove the `while` loop. Otherwise you create new timers until you run out of memory - you need only one. The timer will take care of the repeats. Just call `timer.stop()` when you want to pause.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah use the correct Timmer. This one is for regular Tasks not intended to controll the main game loop. Better switch now, to avoid problems with TimerTask in later development. Why you dont like the truth?